# modifying res object in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I had this idea for a backend design for my SPA-website. I would implement it so that routes starting with "/api/" would return only the relevant data in JSON. all other routes would lead to a full-page load.

Now my idea is to do this in middleware, as such:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next() ){
  if(req.path.split("/")[0]=="api"){
     res.send = res.json;  
     //or other custom response-function, I see many possibilities here!
  }else{
  ...
  }
});
app.use(routes);
```

now, my question is, does this modify the res object globally, or just for the current request (this instance of res)? My understanding is just the current one gets modified, and as far as I can tell thats true, but node is blazingly fast, so it's kinda hard to test on my own ( one can only refresh so many tabs in a millisecond! ) anyone know for sure?

Edit: A lot of the people answering my question have asked why I would want to do this. The point is to abstract what the server does for requests coming from clients with the front-end loaded, and clients who need the full page. I'm also considering the possibility of adding a route for loading partial templates, using this same method. by modifying res.send my controllers can worry about getting the data and send it of, res.send will already know if there needs to be some rendering involved. On second thought though res.send is really useful on its own, I might modify res to have res.answer or similar instead.(makes for less confusion too!)

Comment: I think it's globally. If you unsure of it, you can put a log (ex console.log or whatever) and check it.

Comment: `res` is one instance of a type of object.  You're only modifying that one instance.  node.js can easily have multiple requests/responses in play at once each with their own `res` object.

Comment: You can totally do this - it's not like you're modifying the prototype. But the real question is why you would want to do it this way. Particularly given that if you pass an object or array to res.send it automatically operates as if you called res.json. Read the doc. http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send

Comment: Also, your last sentences suggests that you have a fundamental misapprehension with what is going on in Node. If you in fact did modify the object's prototype (which is what you are trying to convey when you talk about modifying it globally) it wouldn't matter when you checked it (provide node hadn't cycled) - the prototype would still be changed.

Comment: I guess the actual use-case would be to switch it to a res.render if the url does not start with "/api/" , or some other function to fetch the correct view. I guess the interesting part of this method would really be what could go in the else block of my example. but yeah, logging something to remind developers whats going on might be a good idea, this is kind of "outside the box", but that was also kind of the point of the design!

Comment: I think I understand what you are driving at, and I also think whatever you may want to do you will be able to accomplish without overriding `res.send()`. For example, why wouldn't you just have your function call `res.render()` if you want to render something? My two cents on this, is if "outside the box" is the "point" of the design, you should not employ that design. If you need to go outside the box to solve a problem, that is a different matter. Good luck with it in any case. I am a big fan of Express. Also, thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: I should probably mention that this is more of an experimental design, to see if I can find more efficient ways of doing stuff, than an actual production app. thus the "out of the box" point. Can't be more efficient if I keep doing the same thing, right? If nothing else this is sure to deepen my understanding of node and express! =) I'll let you know if I come up with something revolutionary (unlikely, but who knows?)hey- thanks for answering!

Comment: I agree on the value of experimentation; that is very helpful context. And the ease with which can do those sorts of experiments may be one of the things I most enjoy about Javascript as a language. Have fun with it and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to make this an answer because sometimes future readers don't read the comments.

1) You can modify `res` and its members to your heart's content. You are operating on an instance of response, not its prototype. There is no "global" resource, but it does have a prototype.

2) Reading [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send) will pay off here. `res.send` operates identically to `res.json` if it is passed an object or array. Which is to say that the rest of your code will, in the typical case, run no differently than if you didn't monkey with `res.send()` but will confuse the heck out of someone (maybe you) several months or years later.

Comment: Would like to comment that `res.json()` also internally calls `res.end()`, while `res.send()` does not.

Comment: That is correct. However I am not sure what you're driving at as `res.send()` calls `res.json()` (which calls `res.end()`) if called with an object or array. Like I said - it operates identically if passed an object or array. https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L134

Comment: Ahh, I see, I was not aware of this fact.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and each time a request came the response object had the original send function instead of the changed value. So no, it doesn't change it globally.

Here is the test I did:

```
app.use(function(req, res){
    console.log(res.send);
    res.send = 'a';
    console.log(res.send);
});
```

Though I'm still not quite sure why you want to do this? It seems like it would be very confusing when someone looks at your API routes and sees `res.send()` but the effect instead is that of `res.json`. Why can't you use `res.json` in your API route functions?